# Keeping alias field names on CSV export using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, csv, cursor

I'm exporting my feature class to a CSV file. I figured how to keep the fields I need on export.

Is there a way to keep the alias field name on export?

I'm also open to writing out the correct headers but can't figure out how.

```
#Export out as CSV
out_folder_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outputCSV = os.path.join(out_folder_path, "Points" + ".csv")
fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
fieldsToKeep =['REPORTER','RECOWNER','SCINAME','COMNAME','RECBASIS','GlobalID','OCCSTATUS','MANAGESTAT',
               'POPSTAT','OBSDATE','COUNTRY','STATE','COUNTY','PRIVATE','LATITUDE','LONGITUDE',
               'ABUNDANCE','INFESTAREA','INFESTUNIT','PCTCOVER','VISITTYPE','COMMENTS']

field_names = [field.name for field in fields if field.name in fieldsToKeep]

with open(outputCSV,'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(field_names)
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc):
        field_vals = [row.getValue(field.name) for field in fields if field.name in fieldsToKeep]
        w.writerow(field_vals)
    del row
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for the 'field' class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/field.htm) explains that the `.aliasName` attribute holds the value of the field alias.  So change the `field_names =` line to this:

```py
        field_names = [field.aliasName for field in fields if field.name in fieldsToKeep]
```

Or if you want to be a bit clearer, change it to this:

```py
        field_aliases = [field.aliasName for field in fields if field.name in fieldsToKeep]
        ...
        ...
        ...
            w.writerow(field_aliases)
```